# OData request about metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I had followed the tutorial about, how to create OData endpoint on the page http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint.
It works as expected[image]
The request about metadata, it works as expected to:
[image]
When I make a request to url http://localhost:21937/Products, then I've got all entries from products
[image]
My questions are:

- What is the rootservice of this?
- How can I query the ressource types like
  ResourceTypes('Namespace.Product')

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what you mean root service, but if you mean how to route a call to an action of controller, in this sample, OData Web API routing conversion is been used, and more detail can refer to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions
2. If you mean the type information, the you can query http://localhost:21937/$metadata